# Setting dictionary tuple values directly

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples, value-type

Is it possible to do something similar to this: `dictTupleTest[key].Item1 = toggle;` in the following situation?

```
Dictionary<int, (bool, bool)> dictTupleTest = new Dictionary<int, (bool, bool)>();
var key = 3;
var toggle = false;

dictTupleTest.Add(key, (true, false));

//This works
dictTupleTest[key] = (toggle, dictTupleTest[key].Item2);

//While this gives an error
dictTupleTest[key].Item1 = toggle;
```

The error: `Error CS1612: Cannot modify the return value of 'Dictionary<int, (bool, bool)>.this[int]' because it is not a variable.`

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: [Built-in Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple) are immutables. Once created they are read-only. Thus you need to change the whole set.

Comment: Instead of tuple use class object and define your properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples are immutable; the fact that it's stored in a dictionary is irrelevant. You'd get the same error with:

```
var x = dictTupleTest[key];
x.Item1 = toggle;
```

If you want to change one of the values, then don't use a tuple - use a mutable class. Otherwise, the way you're doing it is appropriate (keeping the second value).

EDIT -

Thanks to Theodor Zoulias for pointing out that my reasoning was flawed.  The tuple is mutable, but for some reason (I'm not sure why), you can't change a property of the tuple inline with a dictionary accessor. That error is more common when you try to use mutation operators on a return value (like  `dictTupleTest[key]++`), but I don't see why calling a property `set` shouldn't be allowed.

In any case, assigning the result to a variable *does* work:

```
dictTupleTest.Add(key, (true, false));
var x = dictTupleTest[key];
x.Item1 = false;

Console.WriteLine(dictTupleTest[key]);  // outputs (false, false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from .NET 6, it is possible to update a mutable value-type stored in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` without doing more than one operations on the dictionary. The new API is the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluerefornullref) method:

> Gets either a reference to a `TValue` in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, or a reference null if it does not exist in the dictionary.

It can be used like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//...
CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(dictTupleTest, key).Item1 = toggle;
```

In case the `key` is not found in the dictionary, the above code will throw a `NullReferenceException`. For better control you can use a [ref local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-locals) like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
//...
ref var entry = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(dictTupleTest, key);
if (Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref entry)) throw new KeyNotFoundException();
entry.Item1 = toggle;
```

The `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef` API is non easily discoverable, and [this is intentional](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27062#issuecomment-880601478):

> This is niche unsafe API that 99% of .NET developers should not ever use. We do not want to encourage people to use it just because of they can.